# How to add a y label for each subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.ylabel("raw")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.ylabel("smooth")

ax1.plot(a)

ax2.plot(smoothdata())

plt.show()
```

I need to be able to add y axis labels to each of the plots, i know how to do it with just one plot by doing plt.ylabel('raw") but how do i do it with multiple plots?

Answer (score 0):

Axes object do not have method `ylabel`, use `set_ylabel`

Answer (score 0):

`ylabel()` would be valid for `matplotlib.pyplot`. From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel.html):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel(ylabel, fontdict=None, labelpad=None, **kwargs)
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylabel("Label on plt")
plt.show()
```

If you have multiple plots (subplots) you must use `set_ylabel()` on each subplot axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.set_ylabel("raw") ### <---
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.set_ylabel("smooth") ### <---

ax1.plot([i for i in range(0, 10)], [i for i in range(0, 10)])
ax2.plot([i for i in range(0, 20)], [i for i in range(0, 20)])
plt.show()
```

**Outputs:**

[image: plt]